# Is it remains unchanged or remain unchanged in a conjunction sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions

I'm writing a bullet point in a presentation.  I want to say:

- Our partner and customer commitment remains unchanged.

However, it feels like it reads better if I change it to:

- Our partner and customer commitment remain unchanged.

I know if I read them separately, remains is correct.

I've searched Google, and "remains" is more common.  Should I use remain or remains?

Comment: What remains unchanged? Is it one thing (commitment) or two things (partner remains unchanged, and customer commitment remains unchanged)?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  It's the same thing for two different groups.  Our commitment to our partners and our commitment to our customers remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I’ve posted an answer.

Comment: People write the word *remains* more often for their needs, and that makes the word more correct here or at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If the thing that remains unchanged is the (singular) commitment, which you describe as one of “partner and customer”, then use singular agreement: “remains unchanged”.

On the other hand, perhaps you kept the partner and you’re still committed to the customer (which is getting into zeugma territory) - use plural agreement. Or more likely, if you consider your partner commitment and your customer comment to be separate commitments, use the plural “commitments” and plural agreement.